# How to write a query in Oracle which combines/joins the results of two queries into one

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, where-clause

If my INPUT DATA is as shown below:

```
id1Number id2String   id3String     blob1       blob2       last_updated_timestamp
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1         1-1         11-11                     ...         2020/01/01
2         2-1         22-11         ...         ...         2020/01/02
3         3-1                       ...                     2020/01/01
4         4-1         44-11         ...                     2020/01/05
5         5-1         55-11                                 2020/01/01
6         6-1         66-11                     ...         2020/02/02
7         7-1         77-11         ...                     2020/02/03
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT
I want to write a Query3 which combines the results of Query1 and Query2 in a single query and will get the output shown below

```
select id1Number, id2String, id3String 
from table
where ...

id1Number id2String   id3String
-------------------------------
1         1-1                  
4                     44-11    
5         5-1         55-11
```

Query1

```
select id1Number, id2String 
from table 
where blob1 is NULL and 
      last_updated_timestamp >= to_timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') and 
      last_updated_timestamp <  to_timestamp('2020-02-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS');

id1Number id2String
-------------------
1         1-1      
5         5-1
```

Query2

```
select id1Number, id3String 
from table 
where blob2 is NULL and 
      id3String is NOT NULL and 
      last_updated_timestamp >= to_timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') and 
      last_updated_timestamp <  to_timestamp('2020-02-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS');

id1Number id3String
-------------------
4         44-11    
5         55-11
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm . . . filtering and case expresions:

```
select id1Number,
       (case when blob1 is null then id2String end),
       (case when (blob2 is NULL then id3String  end)
from table 
where (blob1 is NULL or
       (blob2 is NULL and id3String is NOT NULL)
      ) and
      last_updated_timestamp >= to_timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') and 
      last_updated_timestamp <  to_timestamp('2020-02-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS');
```

You can switch between `timestamps` and `dates` pretty easily, so the `where` can be simplified to:

```
where (blob1 is NULL or
       (blob2 is NULL and id3String is NOT NULL)
      ) and
      last_updated_timestamp >= date '2020-01-01' and 
      last_updated_timestamp <  date '2020-02-01';
```

Of course, you could also use a `timestamp` literal.

Comment: Thank you @Gordon Linoff. It worked for me. Really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `case` expressions:

```
select id1number,
    case when blob1 is null then id2string end as id2string,
    case when blob2 is null then id3string end as id3string
from mytable
where 
    last_updated_timestamp >= date '2020-01-01'
    and last_updated_timestamp < date '2020-01-02'
    and (blob1 is null or (blob2 is null and id3String is not null))
```

Note that I changed the filtering logic to use literal dates instead of `to_timestamp()`, which shortens the query a bit.

Comment: Thank you @GMB. It worked for me. Really appreciate it